# What can I do if I need another gang in a junction box but there isn't space in the wall?

Tags: switch, studs, junction-box, dimmer-switch

I have a dual gang junction box installed in a space between 2 studs in the wall. I want to add swap the box for a 3-gang box to add another switch for a ceiling fan, however when I took the cover plate off I found that it is nailed directly to studs on both sides. Is there anything I can do to replace it with a bigger box? The wall is exterior and possibly load bearing.

I looked into replacing the 2 current switches with duplex switches, however, one of the lights is an LED (Cree BA21) and its wired on a 3-way dimmer, the Lutron Maestro C+L dimmer along with the corresponding companion dimmer. There doesn't seem to be a dual dimmer for this light in the 3-way configuration (although I could give up the companion 3-way switch).

The only one I could find is the Lutron Skylark dual S2-L, however, it looks funny and I would lose the 3-way. Are there any other options?

Edit: The switch I want to add is for a fan/light so basically another duplex switch.

Comment: What is the other switch for?  Possible to swap that one for a duplex switch?

Comment: You could add a separate 1-gang box on the other side of the stud.

Comment: I upvoted @wallyk's hilarious answer, but I was thinking more in the "not do over" line of just add another dual-gang above/below the one you have (leave a blank on half of it if not using it all now.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal:  While the photo I chose is potentially humorous, a three gang version wouldn't look silly, yet be easier to wire since it wouldn't require chaining the power feed into both boxes.

Comment: IMPE sideways switches can be annoying due to the non-obvious relationship of a direction to "on" (of course, 3-way switches all have that problem as well.)

Comment: There is probably a good reason why that other stud is there. You would probably have to open up the wall and reframe it to move the stud out of the way. It wouldn't hurt to get an opinion from a structural engineer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are studs at either end of a two gang switch box, that means they are approximately 4 inches apart.  A three gang requires 6 inches.

A switch box is usually about 3.5 inches high; with thickness that means turned sideways, it will fit in a dual ganged space.  So you have room for 20 switches if you want:

[image]

(from [here](http://www.iamanangelchaser.com/processes/switchplates/switchplates.html))

Comment: Haha. I'd love to see this in a house.  It would be especially interesting when the wife got home.